# Why was Anne of Austria so called?

Tags: france, 17th-century, spain, austria, names

[She](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_of_Austria) was a Spanish princess by birth. So why is she called "of Austria"? Is it because [her mother](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margaret_of_Austria,_Queen_of_Spain) was an Austrian princess? But presumably, it should be the person's place of birth that gives them their sobriquet, not their parents'.

Come to think of it, is the name "Anne of Austria" even contemporarily attested? Or is it a later appellation, not used during her lifetime?

UPDATE
As @Semaphore has now convincingly showed, Anne really had the title of Austrian Archduchess (something baldl asserted in wikipedia, but not sourced there). Still, we need to find out why the "of Austria" became her standard sobriquet.

Answer (score 2):

That same wiki post on Anne of Austria contains this line:

> In spite of her birth in Spain, she was referred to as Anne of Austria because the rulers of Spain belonged to the House of Austria.[1]

which answers your question.

Comment: Well, not really. I missed that part somehow, so thanks for spotting it, but it's not really wiki at its best. I mean, I figured out myself that she *could* have been called so because of her familial connections (see my OP). However, wiki gives no citation here so it's not clear that its guess is any more authoritative than mine or yours. (And it could be even an anachronism, as I conjecture). Wiki also claims she was an archduchess but the titles section does not confirm that. So I am still waiting for a weighty source.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg I don't think a source is possible on something that's basically a matter of convention, tbh.

Answer (score 1):

Anne of Austria was a direct descendant of King Charles V of "Austria,"  through her father, King Philip III of Spain. This man's paternal grandfather was Charles V of Austria, who in turn, was the grandson of Maximilian of Austria and Marie of Burgundy, on his father's side, and Ferdinand and Isabella of Spain on his mother's side.

So it's just a matter of Anne of "Austria" inheriting her patrilineal antecedents in her "surname," or designation.